# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException when running dao findAll()

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring+Hibernate+Mysql for web application for development. But in past one week, I always got "nested exception is

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:"

exception when try to run `orgdao.findAll()` to fetch all organization. Even I comments all relation properties, but still no lucky.

**Below are codes:**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "tb_org")
    public class OrgEntity  extends CommonEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private OrgEntity parent;   
  
    @Length(min=1, max=255)
    private String parentIds; 
  
    /*
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="area_id")
    private Area area;      
    */
    @Length(min=0, max=100)
    private String code;    
  
    @Length(min=1, max=100)
    private String name;    

    private Integer type;   
    
    private Integer grade;  
    
    @Length(min=0, max=255)
    private String address; 
    
    @Length(min=0, max=100)
    private String zipCode; 
    
    @Length(min=0, max=100)
    private String master;  
    
    @Length(min=0, max=200)
    private String phone;   
    
    @Length(min=0, max=200)
    private String fax;     
    
    @Length(min=0, max=200)
    private String email; 
       
    /*
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orgEntity", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<UserEntity> userList = Lists.newArrayList();   
    */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<OrgEntity> childList = Lists.newArrayList();

    public OrgEntity getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(OrgEntity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String getParentIds() {
        return parentIds;
    }

    public void setParentIds(String parentIds) {
        this.parentIds = parentIds;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Integer getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(Integer grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getMaster() {
        return master;
    }

    public void setMaster(String master) {
        this.master = master;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getFax() {
        return fax;
    }

    public void setFax(String fax) {
        this.fax = fax;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /*
    public List<UserEntity> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(List<UserEntity> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }
*/
    public List<OrgEntity> getChildList() {
        return childList;
    }

    public void setChildList(List<OrgEntity> childList) {
        this.childList = childList;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }  
}


@MappedSuperclass
public class CommonEntity extends GenericEntity {   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    /**
     * the createUser
     */
    /*
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="createUserId")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties( value={"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})
    private UserEntity createUser;
    */
    /**
     * The createDate.
     */
    @Column(name="createDate")
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createDate;
    
    /**
     * The lastModifyUser.
     */
    /*
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH},fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="lastModifyUser_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties( value={"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})
    private UserEntity lastModifyUser;
    */
    /**
     * The lastModifyDate.
     */
    @Column(name="lastModifyDate")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifyDate;
    
    /*
    @PrePersist
    public void preSave() {
        if((this.getId() == null) && (this.createUser == null)) {
            this.createDate = new Date();
            this.lastModifyDate = new Date();
            //this.createUser = UserUtil.getCurrentUser();
            //this.lastModifyUser = UserUtil.getCurrentUser();
        } else {
            this.lastModifyDate = new Date();
            //this.lastModifyUser = UserUtil.getCurrentUser();
        }
    }

    public UserEntity getCreateUser() {
        return createUser;
    }

    public void setCreateUser(UserEntity createUser) {
        this.createUser = createUser;
    }
*/
    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    /*
    public UserEntity getLastModifyUser() {
        return lastModifyUser;
    }

    public void setLastModifyUser(UserEntity lastModifyUser) {
        this.lastModifyUser = lastModifyUser;
    }
*/
    public Date getLastModifyDate() {
        return lastModifyDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifyDate(Date lastModifyDate) {
        this.lastModifyDate = lastModifyDate;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
    
    
}
```

**The logs below for the reference:**

```
22:39:00.737 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 124 logExceptions - could not extract ResultSet [n/a] com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Query was empty
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:71) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2123) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1911) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:379) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1488) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:329) [spring-data-jpa-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) [spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) [spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) [spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) [spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) [spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) [spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) [spring-data-jpa-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) [spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy166.findAll(Unknown Source) [?:?]
at com.ccgsbj.renewable.base.manager.OrgManager.getAllOrgs(OrgManager.java:82) [classes/:?]
at com.ccgsbj.renewable.base.controller.OrgController.getAllOrgs(OrgController.java:31) [classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:?]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61) [shiro-web-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108) [shiro-web-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137) [shiro-web-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66) [shiro-web-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387) [shiro-core-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178) [spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.45]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_131]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

Comment: Provide a  full `StackTrace` and line-numbers

Comment: thanks for the comments, the full stack trace is too long and cannot post, I deleted part of codes and post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid access to resources, read [Class InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.18.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException.html):

> Root for exceptions thrown when we use a data  access resource incorrectly. Thrown for example on specifying bad SQL when using a RDBMS. Resource-specific subclasses are supplied by concrete data access packages.